# running lithium quickstart with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, lithium

As a newbie, I followed this link:

http://www.blakeerickson.com/posts/2013/04/07/how_to_correctly_configure_ubuntu_to_run_lithium_php

and this link:

http://li3.me/docs/manual/quickstart

to install and run the Lithium tutorial. Everything is OK until the MongoDB accessing. I got the following:

Deprecated: Mongo::__construct(): The 'timeout' option is deprecated. Please use 'connectTimeoutMS' instead in /home/takpo/www/my_app/libraries/lithium/data/source/MongoDb.php on line 261

Quickstart
Manual
API
More

⟁

© Union Of RAD 2013

message and the form items are not seen. Could someone help?

Thanks,

Tak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to Lithium's latest master.
It's caused by PHP mongo extension. if you use < 1.3.4 you won't see the problem, but Lithium latest master fixed it.

Comment: I just delete old my_app and re-install a new one with     git clone git://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework.git my_app
    cd my_app
    git submodule init
    git submodule update

Comment: I just delete old my_app and re-install a new one (I believe latest master inside) use "git" as mentioned in "Installing Lithium", the error remains.  By the way, I recall same error message with the old version of mongodb.

Comment: change timeout to connectTimeoutlineMS in 252 of said MongoDB.php it works now